# Change $\cos x + \sqrt 3 \sin x$ to $2 \sin(x+30)$.

Tags: trigonometry

How to change $\cos x + \sqrt 3 \sin x$ to $2 \sin(x+30)$?

I have no ideas. Sorry for asking this stupid question.

I want to get some hint. Thank you.

Comment: Try the angle sum formula using $2\sin(x+30)$.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) may be useful.

Comment: $\cot 30= \sqrt3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide and multiply by 2, notice that $\sin(30^\circ) = 1/2$ and $\cos(30^\circ) = \sqrt{3}/2$